# Hive table creation using hue interface using space delimiter

Tags: regex, hadoop, hiveql, hue, apache-hive

While creating table using a file in hue-hive interface we have to specify a delimiter. (Tab, Space, Comma etc.) . But my file delimited by one or more spaces. How to specify delimiter to delimit by one or more spaces.

[image]

Comment: Not sure that it is even possible without writing a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table use regex as delimiter via this way:

**Data**, put data to hdfs

```
1  2 3   4
a   b  c d
```

**create table:**

```
//grammar for create table
CREATE TABLE test1(
a string, 
b string, 
c string, 
d string
)
ROW FORMAT  SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  
(
"input.regex" ="([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)\\s+([^\\s]*)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
)  
LOCATION '/test1/';
```